# Issue to add value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, append

I managed to do this :

[image: works]

It's a dict with pokemon's number in `Keys`, and number of victory (vary), name (name) as `Values`

It works and the Out is what I wanted. But as I want to make some visualization after, I felt like dict isn't the best. So I tried the same but to obtain a DataFrame :

[image: doesnt]

But as you can see, the `Out` is an empty df.
The range is 0,10 to try before 0,800. I added prints to see where is the problem. I also tried the 2 #lines, same result.

I juste need something that fill my "brawldf".

It might be a basic issue but I can't manage to find the solution.

Comment: change `brawldf.append(data)` to `brawldf= brawldf.append(data)` and that is it.

Comment: @MEdwin it didn't work for the 1 step .append but it worked for the 2 lines I had in comment. thanks.

Comment: Post code as text, not pictures. We cannot run pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning anything.

You can either use append with:

```
df = df.append({'ID': i}, {'name':name}, {'nbvictory':vary}, ignore_index=True)
```

or assign the new row with iloc to your DataFrame. 
See [docs here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

```
df.iloc[i] = [i, name, vary]
```

*edit: sorry I forgot to add: ignore_index=True, edited my answer. This should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried :

```
brawldf = brawldf.append({'ID': i}, {'name':name}, {'nbvictory':vary})
```

endedd up like this :

[image]

but this one worked :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[name,i,vary]], columns=['name','ID','nbvictory'])
brawldf = brawldf.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
```

also this worked :

```
brawldf.loc[i] = [i, name, vary]
```